# How to Iterate through array of Day Time and display only current week record

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
 ng-repeat="day in task.DailyWorks | limitTo : weekdays.length: weekStart"
```

I am trying to iterate through daily work record in table columns, I want to display current week record first time. Then depends on user Click Previous week or Next week button it will change the records.

Comment: Are you using Angular or AngularJs? You have tagged both and your code looks like AngularJs not Angular.

Comment: @AdrianBrand I am using AngularJs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular 2+ you can iterate using `*ngFor`. DatePipes of **Week of Year** and **Week of Month** are supported since Angular 7.

[As Angular docs of DatePipe says](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

> Week of year:    w
>
> Week of month:   W

[An example at stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6pu7c?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

To show week of month:

```
<h3>Number of week in month: </h3>
<div *ngFor = "let title of data">     
    {{title.CREATE_TS | date:'dd/mm/yyyy'}}
    <br/> Number of week in month is
    {{title.CREATE_TS | date:'W'}}
</div>
```

To show week of year:

```
<div *ngFor = "let title of data">
    {{title.CREATE_TS | date:'dd/mm/yyyy'}}
    <br/> Number of week in year is
    {{title.CREATE_TS | date:'w'}}  
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
data = [
    {
      CREATE_TS: "2018-08-15 17:17:30.0",
      Key1: "Val1",
      Key2: "Val2",
    },
    {
      CREATE_TS: "2018-08-15 17:25:30.0",
      Key1: "Val1",
      Key2: "Val2",
    },
    {
      CREATE_TS: "2018-08-15 17:28:30.0",
      Key1: "Val1",
      Key2: "Val2",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It will display all the record. i need to display only current week

Comment: Working now.. Thank you StepUp